# Tensorflow Serving client does not work

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to build a program to predict from a already trained model, based on  this tutorial

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/flowers

For this, I am using Docker and Tensorflow Serving following up this tutorial:

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-deploy-machine-learning-models-with-tensorflow-part-2-containerize-it-db0ad7ca35a7

When I run the client, which is based on this example:
https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.py

I got this error:

```
userml@userml:~/usermodel$ python tensorflow_serving_client.py --server=172.17.0.2:9000 --image=./image5578.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow_serving_client.py", line 87, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/userml/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "tensorflow_serving_client.py", line 46, in main
    result = stub.Predict(request, 60.0)  # 60 secs timeout
  File "/home/userml/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/beta/_client_adaptations.py", line 324, in __call__
    self._request_serializer, self._response_deserializer)
  File "/home/userml/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/beta/_client_adaptations.py", line 210, in _blocking_unary_unary
    raise _abortion_error(rpc_error_call)
grpc.framework.interfaces.face.face.AbortionError: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details="input size does not match signature")
```

How can I solve this?
I was trying to find input size, to set on 'shape[1]' but seems not work. Does my model has something that is not compatible with the client?

Thanks a lot!